# Restangular Response Interceptor for Headers

Tags: angularjs, restangular, angular-http-interceptors, http-token-authentication

I am communicating from angular app to server side for data. The server creates a token and sends it into the header. I am looking for ways to intercept the response using Restangular and save it in the localStorage. I haven't been successful.

I was doing something like this in my app .config

```
RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor('HttpInterceptor');
```

and then in the HttpInterceptor I was calling the Storage to store the Header. But I am getting several errors and couldn't figure out this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright after much of a research, I finally found a solution that worked for me.

So in my app.js, I included this:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, RestangularProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
}
```

And then I the AuthInterceptor service to do the header extraction.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .factory('AuthInterceptor', AuthenInterceptor);

AuthenInterceptor.$inject = ['$localStorage'];

function AuthenInterceptor($localStorage) {
  return {
    response: function (response) {
      var authToken = response.headers('You Token Name');
      if (authToken) {
        $localStorage.userToken = authToken;
      }
      return response;
    }
  };
}
```

Hope it helps someone with similar problem. Thanks!